# Conflict between hyperref and page numbering?

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering, incompatibility

It looks like there is a conflict between the `hyperref` package and the "page numbering" of a document (maybe with the `fancyhdr` package?). In the following MWE there are 67 warnings. How to solve this incompatibility, and therefore remove the warnings?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
            
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
\def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX}{A link to LaTeX}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

These are some of the 67 warnings:

> Package lipsum Warning: Unknown language 'latin'. Hyphenation patterns for 'english' will be used instead. With LuaTeX, lipsum requires babel to get proper hyphenation (you can use \usepackage[base]{babel}).

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (1.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 12.0pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\footskip}{12.0pt}.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\setbox' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\z@' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\hbox' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\color@begingroup' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\endgraf' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\endgroup' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\ht' on input line 29.
```

etc...

**EDITED after the @Ulrike Fischer's comment**

Thanks a lot @Ulrike Fischer,the warnings related to the apparent incompatibility with `hyperref` have disappeared. However, the page numbering is now at the bottom *center* and not at the bottom *right* corner of the page, as I would need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
            
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
% \def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX}{A link to LaTeX}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**How to keep the page numbering at the bottom *right* corner of the page?**

Comment: do not put something like \raisebox inside \thepage.

Comment: thanks a lot, but where to put ```\raisebox{10pt}```then? I tried in other positions, but I continue to get errors... and I need it, so that the page number appears on the page, since the bottom margin is quite small (I need a small bottom margin )......

Comment: \thepage is used in various places, include references (\pageref), table of contents and in internal destination names. So it should contain formatting. Put your raisebox into the fancyhdr definition, e.g. `\cfoot{\raisebox{...}{\thepage}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited my question.... I implemented more or less what you suggested. That solved the issue of the warnings, but the page numbering is now at the bottom center of the page and not at the bottom right as I would need (and as It was in my original question.....) How to adjust this small thing now? :-)

Comment: Well check in the fancyhdr docu what cfoot means and then make an educated guess what you need instead.

Comment: See pages 12 and 46 of the fancyhdr manual.  BTW, `\cfoot` has been depreciated.

Comment: Please don't paste images of code and errors. Anybody who relies on a screen reader is screwed.

Comment: @cfr, I am aware about the "do not paste images of code and errors" even though I disagree, but if you read the question, I pasted the code first, so that anyone can reproduce the errors. Here, "Images of code and errors" are supplementary information for "Anybody who does not rely on a screen reader".

Comment: @Ommo Even for people who do not need a screen reader, it would be much more helpful if you would show the full error message as text. Your images only contain a short part of the error message and often the interesting bits are missing.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks, I edited the part about the errors, removing the picture and adding the text of the errors (just some of them). Hope it is better now..

Comment: @Ommo I replaced the ones I can reproduce with their actual text, including line breaks. It is often important to keep the line breaks in place because in error messages, they will tell you where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that..

Comment: Never assume people can reproduce errors from your code. If that was a reasonable assumption, you could omit the errors confidently. But it's often the case that the details of your errors matter - especially if I get different errors from your code or no errors at all. And the complete text is often essential - especially for the first error, which is almost always the one which matters. Occasionally, it may be the second. But later errors don't mean much unless they persist after earlier ones are fixed. Errors beget errors .... I can copy your code, but I can't duplicate your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @cfr

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of @Ulrike Fischer and @John Kormylo, I got what I wanted.

The trick was to replace this

```
\def\thepage{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{---\arabic{page}---}}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
```

with this

```
\fancyfoot[R]{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{\textbf{---\arabic{page}---}}}}
```

OR with this

```
\fancyfoot[R]{\smash{\raisebox{10pt}{\textbf{--~\thepage~--}}}}
```

Here following the entire working solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = blue,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = blue,
            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
            
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\setlength\footskip{1pt}
% \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[R]{\smash{\raisebox{0.5cm}{\textbf{--~\thepage~--}}}} % \hspace*{1cm}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX}{A link to LaTeX}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]